# Flutter spaces between arcs in a pie chart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add spaces or gaps between arcs by using a pie chart, from this photo:

[arcs without Gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szYQ8.jpg)
to this photo with gaps:
[arcs with gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xErnH.png)
this is the code:

```
class PieChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<MockData> mockDataList;
  PieChartPainter(
    this.mockDataList,
  );
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final c = Offset(size.width / 2.0, size.height / 2.0);
    final raidus = size.width * 0.9;
    final rect = Rect.fromCenter(center: c, width: raidus, height: raidus);
    var startAngle = 0.0;
    for (var di in mockDataList) {
      var sweepAngle = di.percentage * 360.0 * pi / 180.0;
      final paint = Paint()
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = 16
        ..color = di.color;
      canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint);
      startAngle += sweepAngle;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```